# Temperature problem find the fastest growth trajectory for $T(x,y)100-x^2-3y^2$ form the point $(5,4)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

A particle that can sense temperature is situated on the point (5,4) of a metallic plate. In the temperature in $(x,y)$ is defined by $ T(x,y)=100-x^2-3y^2$. What is the trajectory in which the particle if it moves continuously in the direction of fastest growth  of temperature.

I started finding the gradient of T

$$\nabla T= (-2x,-6y)$$
Then plugin $(5,4)$
$$ \nabla T (5,4)=(-10,-24)$$
Then finding the norm and then the unit vector
$$\lambda \nabla T(5,4)$$
And as I know this is the direction of fastest growth, but while showing this to my teacher he answered that it wasn't the trajectory, so how do I find it? He also told me that it can find it using differential equations (I haven't taken the course)or analyzing the geometry.

How can I proceed? any guidance is highly appreciated

Comment: I dont know if it can be solved by using Lagrange multipliers, any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

at any point, $(x,y)$ the direction of maximal change will be: $(x', y') = (-2x, -6y)$

solve the diff eq
$x'= -2x\\
y' = -6y$

$x,y = (Ae^{-2t}, Be^{-6t})$

at $t = 0$ solve for $A,B$

$x,y = (5e^{-2t}, 4e^{-6t})$

Comment: How can I solve it without using differential equations? As I dont know how to solve them

Comment: If you made a contour map of lines of equal temperature, then you would see a set of concentric ellipses that make each contour.  The path of maximal change crosses each contour at a right angle.  This will at least give you a picture of the path.  I am not sure how to get from this picture to an equation, but maybe it will suffice.